# How can I copy from local to a remote location with credentials in PowerShell?

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am a fresh beginner to PowerShell.

I have username and password to reach a shared folder in a remote location.

I need **to copy the file `foo.txt` from the current location to** `\\Bar.foo.myCOmpany.com\logs` within a PS1 script that is written for **Powershell v3.0**.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: remote location is a network share or an ftp folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy-Item doesn't support the -credential parameter, This does parameter appear
but it is not supported in any Windows PowerShell core cmdlets or providers"

You can try the below function to map a network drive and invoke copy

```
Function Copy-FooItem {

param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [string]$username,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [string]$password
        )

$net = New-Object -com WScript.Network
$drive = "F:"
$path = "\\Bar.foo.myCOmpany.com\logs"
if (test-path $drive) { $net.RemoveNetworkDrive($drive) }
$net.mapnetworkdrive($drive, $path, $true, $username, $password)
copy-item -path ".\foo.txt"  -destination "\\Bar.foo.myCOmpany.com\logs"
$net.RemoveNetworkDrive($drive)

}
```

Here's how you can run the function just change the parameters for username and password

```
Copy-FooItem -username "powershell-enth\vinith" -password "^5^868ashG"
```

Comment: Do I need to close connections before and/or after to target server? I came across that it is necessery when I was browsing the net?

Comment: Anyway, I am having an error when I try this:
rrorMessage:  The FileSystem provider supports credentials only on the New-PSDrive cmdlet. Perform the operation again without specifying credentials..Exception.Message
At line:1 char:1

Comment: hi try it now Copy-Item doesn't support the -credential parameter, This does parameter appear but it is not supported in any Windows PowerShell core cmdlets or providers" we can map the network drive and make it work, just try and let me know

Answer (score 4):

I'd make use of BITS.  Background Intelligent Transfer Service.

If BitsTransfer module not implemented for your session:

```
Import-Module BitsTransfer
```

Sample of using it to transfer a file using a credentials:

```
$cred = Get-Credential()
$sourcePath = \\server\example\file.txt
$destPath = C:\Local\Destination\
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $sourcePath -Destination $destPath -Credential $cred
```

*Caveat*: If you are executing script within a RemotePS session, then BITS is *NOT* supported.

Get-Help for Start-BitsTransfer:

SYNTAX

```
 Start-BitsTransfer [-Source] <string[]> [[-Destination] <string[]>] [-Asynchronous] [-Authentication <string>] [-Credential <PS
Credential>] [-Description <string>] [-DisplayName <string>] [-Priority <string>] [-ProxyAuthentication <string>] [-ProxyBypass
 <string[]>] [-ProxyCredential <PSCredential>] [-ProxyList <Uri[]>] [-ProxyUsage <string>] [-RetryInterval <int>] [-RetryTimeou
t <int>] [-Suspended] [-TransferType <string>] [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [<CommonParameters>]
```

More help...

Here is script to create $cred object so you aren't prompted for username/passwod:

```
    #create active credential object
    $Username = "user"
    $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString ‘pswd’ -AsPlainText -Force
    $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Username, $Password
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
copy-item -path .\foo.txt  -destination \remoteservername\logs -credential (get-credential)
```

Comment: But where do I pass the user name and password?

Comment: `get-credential` open a windows for input-in userid & password. Do you need to read them from file?

Comment: read this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239647/using-powershell-credentials-without-being-prompted-for-a-password

Comment: this just gives an error 'The FileSystem provider supports credentials only on the New-PSDrive cmdlet' for me