# Copying from one server to other with credentials

Tags: copy, credentials, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to copy a file from one server to another server so that it doesn't ask me to enter my login info and I don't have to store the password blatently in the code.  The problem is, it's still coming up with a credential request GUI, even though I give the -Credential parameter.  This is how I store the password in a file:

```
read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file C:\secString.txt
```

Then the code looks like this:

```
function GetSecureLogin() {
   $username = "usa02xxxswg2\20xbackup"
   $password = get-content C:\secString.txt | convertto-securestring
   $cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
}

function CopyFileToFolder ([string]$Source, [string]$destination){
   Copy-Item "$Source" -Destination "$destination" -Credential $cred  #this is where the login info box is coming up but shouldn't be
}

######################start here#####################
$cred = ""
GetSecureLogin

$tempSource = "filename.txt"
$ToLocation = "$ToLoc"
CopyFileToFolder $tempSource $ToLoc
```

Any ideas?  I'm relatively new to PowerShell, so I could be doing something silly.  I'm not sure how to tell if $cred is getting back to my Copy function ok or if it's out of scope.

I've looked at these examples but I'm having trouble deciding if I need to do something different because they are specifying the server info and I'm trying to avoid that since I just want to use UNC path like I was doing before.  The copying was working fine without login because I was using my Active Directory login to save the task.  Now we want to use a locally saved login (where the script is run) and then it needs a different local login when it's trying to access the other server.

[copy-item with alt cred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612015/copy-item-with-alternate-credentials), 
[powershell without prompt for cred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239647/using-powershell-credentials-without-being-prompted-for-a-password), 
[copy without cred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239377/how-can-i-copy-from-local-to-a-remote-location-with-credentials-in-powershell), 
[copy with alt cred](http://powershell.org/wp/forums/topic/copy-with-alternate-credentials/), 
[cred without password prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239647/using-powershell-credentials-without-being-prompted-for-a-password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out.  I did it like this link.  It was a little tricky in that I didn't have to use the directory that came after my sharename, but once I got rid of the subdirectory, it worked.

[copy with credentials and New-PSDrive](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/21/improving-the-filesystem-provider-through-community-feedback.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to figure out if returning $cred from my GetSecureLogin function, and assigning it to $cred in the main part of the script will fix the problem where it's asking me for the login info when I do the copy.  It looks like my co-worker moved all the directories, so I still have to test this once I figure out where he moved them to.

Comment: It looks like the server was failed over to the other side, but once I tested it with the directories visible on the server I was running my script on, it's having problem with my using -Credential option for Copy-item command.  <"The filesystem provider supports credentials only on the New-PSDrive cmdlet. Perform the operation again without specifying credentials.">  Any idea how to do the copy without having to fill the credentials in the popup window?  I'm not sure about New-PSDrive cmdlet.

Comment: My copy command looks like this now, but it gives the above error message.  <Copy-Item "$Source" -Destination "$dest" -Credential $cred>