# Error when trying to run .bat file using runas Administrator using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I can right click on the DEC16.bat file and it will run. I am having trouble including it in a script to run from a flash drive.
The PowerShell script essentially copies over a bunch of install files onto a client's computer.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS H:\> $script = "\\xxxhsfmsl03\adap\Database\Install\AugKA\DEC16.bat"
PS H:\>
PS H:\> Start-Process powershell -Credential “xxx\xxxvis_desktop” -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command &{Start-Process $script -verb runas}'
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The directory name is invalid.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Process powershell -Credential “xxx\xxxvis_desktop” -ArgumentList '-noprof ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

PS H:\> $script
\\xxxhsfmsl03\adap\Database\Install\AugKA\DEC16.bat
PS H:\>
```

(I have inserted "xxx"'s to protect the innocent)

Comment: ArgumentList is quoted with single quotes. Therefore $script wont expand. Use double quotes

Comment: If you got this code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305696/running-a-bat-file-as-admin-from-powershell) I understand. I see you left a comment there yesterday. I also left one pointing out the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Start-Process powershell `
   -WorkingDirectory (Split-Path $script) `
   -Credential xxx\xxxvis_desktop `
   -ArgumentList '-noprofile', '-command', "
     & { start-process powershell -ArgumentList '-File', '$script' -Verb RunAs }
     "
```

- Your primary problem was most likely that **the target user - `xxx\xxxvis_desktop` - lacked permission to access what happened to be the *current* directory at the time of invocation**.

  - **Setting the working directory explicitly to a directory the target user *is* allowed to access should fix that problem** - `-WorkingDirectory (Split-Path $script)` sets the working dir. to the dir. in which the target script is located.
- Your secondary problem - as pointed out in a comment on the question by [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3829407/matt) - is that the **command string** you passed to `Start-Process` was **enclosed in `'...'` (*single* quotes), causing the embedded `$script` variable reference *not* to be expanded** (interpolated).

  - **Using `"..."` (*double* quotes) fixes that problem;** note, however, that the command line to pass to the `powershell` executable is split into *individual arguments* passed via `-ArgumentList` - the (literal, single-quoted) options, followed by the (interpolated, double-quoted) command string, which is the preferable way to pass arguments, because it is more robust.
  - Note, how the `$string` reference inside the command string is enclosed in *embedded* `'...'` so as to ensure that when the invoked `powershell` instance parses the command string, the value of `$string` is recognized as a *single* argument (although this happens not to be necessary for the value at hand, `\\xxxhsfmsl03\adap\Database\Install\AugKA\DEC16.bat`).

    - If there's a chance that the value of `$script` has embedded `'` instances, you must use the following (double the `'` instances to escape them):
      `$($script -replace "'", "''")`
- The final problem is that you cannot use `Start-Process` directly on a *script* - as in the outer call, you need to call `powershell` and pass it the script filename as an argument.

---

Additional notes:

- The `& { ... }` wrapper around the `start-process` call in the command string shouldn't be necessary.
- Generally, you could use a *single* `Start-Process` call with `-Verb RunAs` to elevate the run of `$script`, but, unfortunately, `-Verb RunAs` and `-Credential` cannot be combined, so that means:

  - If the current user is an administrative account, the elevated session will invariably run as that user - you'll just get a yes/no prompt to confirm elevation.
  - Otherwise, the credentials will be prompted for, but you cannot pre-populate the username in that dialog.
  - `Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell -ArgumentList '-noprofile', '-File', $script`

Comment: It works. And you are correct, I  cannot pre-populate the username by putting "-Credential myUserNameHere" ::: and thank you very much!