# Powershell Secure password to work on any machine

Tags: powershell, passwords

I need to write a powershell script that i can run on any machine to connect to a server.
Does the secure-string encrypt using the machine or user i.e will a secure password work on any machine in the domain or can it only be decrypted on the machine it was created on.  If it is the latter is there away to encrypt the password so i can run the script on any machine

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To work on other machines you'll need to create a key for use with the ConvertTo-SecureString and ConvertFrom-SecureString cmdlets.

```
PS C:\> $Key = (3,4,2,3,56,34,254,222,1,1,2,23,42,54,33,233,1,34,2,7,6,5,35,43)
PS C:\>$StandardString = ConvertFrom-SecureString  $SecureString -Key $Key
```

http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/06/01/securestrings-in-powershell/

> By default, the SecureString cmlets use Windows’ Data Protection API
>   when they convert your SecureString to and from a plain text
>   representation.  The encryption key is based on your Windows logon
>   credentials so only you can decrypt the data that you’ve encrypted. 
>   **If you want the exported data to work on another system or separate
>   user account, you can use the parameter sets that let you provide an
>   explicit key.**

Comment: how secure is it having the key in the script?

Comment: Its not. That would be like putting the cleartext password in there.

Answer (score 0):

That's a great question. [Here's a link to how to save your credential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239647/using-powershell-credentials-without-being-prompted-for-a-password). I got this set up and I'm going to try my credential string on another computer logged in with another account. I'll let you know my result.

**Update**

I would have to say it didn't work for me. I went on the other person's machine logged in as them. I have my Credentials set up in a script called `Get-MyCred`:

```
$username = 'Domain\MyName'
$password = cat '\\server\share\securestring.txt' | convertto-securestring
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password

return $cred
```

When I run the line where it gets my password I get an error on the other persons machine.

```
ConvertTo-SecureString : Key not valid for use in specified state.
At line:1 char:56
+ Get-Content O:\BCKUP\MyScripts\Cred\securestring.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], CryptographicException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ImportSecureString_InvalidArgument_CryptographicError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand
```

I even get the error when I log into another computer with my credentials.

Comment: that would be great if you could let me know i just want a custom script that i can run on certain machines to change the ou and was going to use enter-pssession -computername dc1 -credentials user 

get-adcomputer %computername% | Move-ADObject -TargetPath 'ou=test,dc=test,dc=com'

Comment: You might save the password in plain text? Make it a Hidden file?

Comment: interesting there must be away to do this i really don't want to risk having my admins password in a plain text. Thanks for having a look though