# Understanding Powershell SecureStrings

Tags: powershell, session, securestring

today, I wanted to dig deeply into the concept of SecureString .NET and Powershell, yet I don't think, I am understanding it very well.

If I have a password and convert it to a securestring. Is it saved as I entered it? (Being both encrypted or plain text).

Now if I would pass the password as a part of a PSCredential to a PSSession: what would happen? Does PSSession run ConvertFrom-SecureString on the passed password? But then the password is being encrypted again. How does it know how to pass it to a PSSesion?

Comment: did you try google? see: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4546.working-with-passwords-secure-strings-and-credentials-in-windows-powershell.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Avshalom. I may didn't explain myself very well. My question was considering the way SecureStrings are being handled internally by a PSSession. Especially the point where they are being decrypted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question but get the jist. This will probably be easier if you think in terms of **object types** ([some explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/viewing-object-structure--get-member-?view=powershell-6)). [This link is now dead.]

> *"If I have a password and convert it to a securestring. Is it saved as
> I entered it? (Being both encrypted or plain text)"*

- Your password will be plain text, and have the type `[String]`. This is not encrypted.
- The SecureString has the type `[System.Security.SecureString]`. It is encrypted.
- This encryption happens [**in memory** whenever you create the `SecureString`](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4546.working-with-passwords-secure-strings-and-credentials-in-windows-powershell.aspx).
- It's important to note that a key is required to decrypt the `SecureString` (more on that below)

**Approach 1**
This creates an **encrypted** `SecureString` variable called `$SecurePassword`. The unencrypted password does not make it to memory.

```
$SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString
```

**Approach 2**
This creates an **unencrypted** `String` variable `$PlainPassword`, *then* a `SecureString` variable.

```
$PlainPassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password"
$SecurePassword = $PlainPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
```

---

> *"Now if I would pass the password as a part of a PSCredential to a PSSession: what would happen?"*

- PSSession does not accept unencrypted passwords. To simplify you can either provide a `User` and be prompted for a password, or pass an object that has the type `PSCredential` - i.e. it is expecting a **secure password**.
- When you a pass a `PSCredential`, it is already encrypted with the password as a `SecureString`.
- But the PSSession needs to decrypt it (this part I am not sure on but assume... how else can it varify it?)
- To decrypt the `SecureString`, the key is required. The key is normally generated and as long as both machines have the same [security principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_(computer_security)), the PSSession can complete the decryption (this part I'm sure of)
- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580523/powershell-secure-password-to-work-on-any-machine) addresses how to create a key so that a `SecureString` can be decrypted when there there are different principles.

Comment: I see. Just to be sure:
If a password is being encrypted on `ConvertTo-SecureString`: What does happen on `ConvertFrom-SecureStrin`? Is it just a convertion to a encrypted text, and not a on memory one?

This Text needs to be passed to a `PSSession`: Does the Session decrypt it? (To a Hash I guess).  Else how would the machine be able to start with an encrypted password? The keys used are located on the machine initiating the `PSSession` call.

Comment: @Mahmoud [`ConvertFrom-SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertfrom-securestring?view=powershell-6) can accept a key, if used to originally encrypt the string. Otherwise it will use [Windows DAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx). For PSSession, read about the [-Authentication parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession?view=powershell-6).

Comment: @Mahmoud If you've found this answers your questions, please consider [accepting/voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)