# New-PSSession works only on specific device in same domain

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am using `New-PSSession` to create session and connect to our server.

Code I am using looks like this:

```
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $passwordPlain -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $userName, $PWord
$serverSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $serverName -Credential $credentials
```

And it works perfectly. But if my colleague runs it on his PC with same parameters it fails with error: `The user name or password is incorrect. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.`

It looks like my colleague does not have permissions to connect there. If this is the case, what are `$credentials` for?

We have tried setting `-Authentication` to different type, but with no luck.
Then we tried different credentials on my PC and it works.

Have anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15581334/9898643) and [that](https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-2/). SecureStrings created on one machine cannot be used from another machine unless you provide an encryptuion key using the `-Key` parameter.