# Schedule a Job in Powershell 3.0

Tags: scheduled-tasks, powershell-3.0

I am working on PS script that will run a task once the computer has been logged in. Here is how I schedule the task:

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtLogOn
Register-ScheduledJob -Name TestSchedule -FilePath <filepath> -Trigger $trigger
```

The script scheduled to run does nothing but launch the command prompt, however nothing is being run once I log in to the computer. I have tried tinkering with it all I could but I get nothing.

Comment: Are you specifying the full (absolute) path to your script file? What happens if you manually execute the scheduled job, either through Task Scheduler or with `Get-ScheduledJob <ID> | Start-Job`?

Comment: @alroc I am using the full path. So far I tried to run it manually within task scheduler but doesnt work. I will try with `Get-ScheduledJob <ID> | Start-Job`

Comment: You may need to run the job as admin.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239647/using-powershell-credentials-without-being-prompted-for-a-password/6240319#6240319
and here: https://gist.github.com/wpsmith/4190b9a03bc1544a7df5

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best best solution but you could try putting the other script into this "job-script". Like This. Works Fine for me.

```
$jobname     = "xyz"
$JobTrigger  = New-JobTrigger -Weekly -At "03:00 AM" -DaysOfWeek Saturday
$MyOptions   = New-ScheduledJobOption -ContinueIfGoingOnBattery -HideInTaskScheduler
Register-ScheduledJob -name "$jobname" -scriptblock {$myscript} -trigger $JobTrigger –ScheduledJobOption $MyOptions
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your code lacks this command:

```
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName $name -TaskPath Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs -Principal (New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -L Interactive -U $env:USERNAME)
```

`$name` is the name of your scheduledjob, this command makes the job interactive to the user, if your code still doesn't work, check out this script:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PC-Utilities-Downloader-355e5bfe