# WiX: installer fails in ConfigureUsers action when installing from remote computer

Tags: powershell, wix, wix3.7

I have a WiX MSI installer for an ASP.NET website that runs on `my_server`. The package is installed via a very simple Powershell script `install.ps1` that just calls `msiexec` with some parameters.

### The problem

When I run `install.ps1` directly on `my_server`, everything is fine. But when I want to run `install.ps1` on `my_server` from a remote machine (e.g. `build_server`), the installation fails with error code 1603 and the MSI install log reveals the the following error:

> Action start 14:22:30: ConfigureUsers.
>
> ConfigureUsers:  Error 0x80070005: failed to add/remove User actions
>
> CustomAction ConfigureUsers returned actual error code 1603

Any suggestions?

### Extra information

- I run `install.ps1` remotely with the following command:

  ```
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName my_server -ScriptBlock { path\to\install.ps1 } -Authentication Negotiate
  ```
- I use the same user credentials on both `my_server` and `build_server`.
- In the WiX definition, the website is set up with a specific user account for the app pool, like this:

  ```
  <Component Id="AppPoolCmp"
             Guid="a-fine-looking-guid"
             KeyPath="yes">
    <util:User Id="AppPoolUser"
               CreateUser="no"
               RemoveOnUninstall="no"
               Name="[APP_POOL_IDENTITY_NAME]"
               Password="[APP_POOL_IDENTITY_PWD]"
               Domain="[APP_POOL_IDENTITY_DOMAIN]">
    </util:User>
    <iis:WebAppPool Id="AppPool"
                    Name="[APP_POOL_NAME]"
                    ManagedPipelineMode="Classic"
                    ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0"
                    Identity="other"
                    User="AppPoolUser">
      <iis:RecycleTime Value="5:00" />
    </iis:WebAppPool>
  </Component>
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely to be the [double hop issue](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop.aspx), your credentials are not valid beyond the scope of the first server.

Can you do the command with the option:

```
-Authentication CredSSP
```

Rather than `Negotiate`.

You will also need to specify credentials manually using the `-Credentials` flag as well as set up the client and server for CredSSP:

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer HOSTNAME -Force
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server -Force
```

The steps are explained in more detail [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-quot-second-hop-quot-functionality-with-credssp.aspx).

Comment: Ok, so after setting the server and client up for CredSSP, the installation script now seems to run without the error. However, I do get a popup asking for my password which I did not using negotiate. Since the script is supposed to run by itself on a build-server using a service account, is it possible to use CredSSP without having to write the password inline?

Comment: It seems [storing the password as a secure string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239647/using-powershell-credentials-without-being-prompted-for-a-password) is my only option. I will appreciate any other tips but I'll go ahead and mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: I've not found a way to achieve this without storing the password in some form.