# Using SMTPServer and Powershell to send emails, but what is the password parameter?

Tags: powershell, smtp, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I just used the tasty function of sending mails with powershell. 
I use the -credentials parameter for login my windows account. Now I want the programm to send mails automatically without putting my password. 
Is there a password parameter? Or is it to insecure?
Do you guys have a way to put the password in from a secured file or whatever?

Thats what I just used :

```
Send-Mailmessage -to "$recipients" -from "$sender" -Subject "Deployment Announcer" -body "Testmail" -SMTPserver "xxx.xx.xxx.xx" -Credential "Administrator"
```

Comment: If you're using an internal smtp server it may not require authentication, so you may not need the credential parameter at all.  If you want this to run as a scheduled task, and your smtp server requires authentication, you'd typically schedule the task using an account that has permissions to use the relay, and pass it's credentials.  Storing credentials is possible, but generally considered bad practice.

Comment: sometimes my email script works, sometimes it doesn't. I don't have to put the $PSEmailServer into my powershell profile, correct? I didn't give him the port which is 30 and it worked without, any idea why? thanks

Comment: If you dom't set $PSEmailServer, then you must specify the SMTPServer parameter in send-mailmessage.  The default port for SMTP is 25, and it will use that if you don't specify a port. You need to be more specific about "not working".  If it gives an error, what is the error? If it runs but you don't get the email then you may need to investigate message tracking or your spam quarantine.

Comment: thats what i thought, our port is 30 and it was working without giving him the port. maybe we have another one in this house and i dont know it.

Comment: Use telnet from the command line to test SMTP communication: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153119

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/koteshb/archive/2010/02/13/powershell-creating-a-pscredential-object.aspx) indicates, you can create a PSCredential object using your account name and password as below, and then use the created object as the value after `-Credential`

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "PlainTextPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $secpasswd)
```

And you would also find this link useful if you want to store your password into a file first and then the script would read the file instead of prompting you for the password [Using PowerShell credentials without being prompted for a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239647/using-powershell-credentials-without-being-prompted-for-a-password)

Answer (score 0):

The credentials parameter accepts a psCredential object which can contain a username (including domain) and password (stored securely).  If you want to reuse the credential try

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Send-Mailmessage -to "$recipients" -from "$sender" -Subject "Deployment Announcer" -body "Testmail" -SMTPserver "xxx.xx.xxx.xx" -Credential $cred
```

Get-Credential will prompt you for the username and password, removing the need to store the password in plain text.