# Run powershell as a different user and call Windows Remote Assisant as current logged on user

Tags: powershell

I have created a powershell script that runs with my account for others to use. In the script, it has a button that launches Windows Remote Assist. The problem is, as the script runs with my account, my name appears in the receiver end. I can include -credential but it will prompt for a login detail. Is there a way to launch it as a current user without any prompt?

I have tried to call another ps1 that processes msra /offerra but that still uses my credential.

```
Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/C msra /offerra $StrComputer" -NoNewWindow
```

Is there a way to do it or is it even possible?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [Impersonate a User](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Impersonate-a-User-9bfeff82) and [Use-Impersonation](https://gist.github.com/idavis/856603/72bc0cbefed42e8f7e002ba8fa0adbc5b789151b)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using PowerShell credentials without being prompted for a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239647/using-powershell-credentials-without-being-prompted-for-a-password)