# Encrypting password in powershell before calling to vcenter connect server

Tags: powershell, vcenter

Issue is while running  power shell scripts vcenter passwords is capturing in event logs.

So I am trying  yo encrypt  before we call vcenter.

I am able to encrypt  the password using below

```
$Pass = "P@ssword1" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
```

When I run with encrypted  password  as below

```
Connect-VIServer -Server $serverName -User $userName -Password $pass
```

It's not taking encrypted password  getting  error..

I also tried

```
$Pass = "P@ssword1" | ConvertFrom-SecureString
```

Even long encrypted  data generated not able to pass as password to vcenter

Can you please  help how to pass encrypted  password  to v center

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75612533/21317527

Answer (score 1):

```
function getCred($role,$credPath){
$credMassiv = @()
$array = "" | Select user, Encrypted, role
    if (!(Test-Path "$credPath\cred.csv")){ $cred = setCred $role $credPath }

    if (Test-Path "$credPath\cred.csv"){
        $credMassiv = Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path "$credPath\cred.csv"

        $user = $credMassiv |Where-Object {$_.role -eq $role} |Select-Object -Expand user
        $pwd = $credMassiv |Where-Object {$_.role -eq $role} |Select-Object -Expand Encrypted | ConvertTo-SecureString
        
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($pwd)){$cred = setCred $role $credPath}
        else {$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $pwd}
    }
    

$cred
}

function setCred($role,$credPath){
    $credMassiv = @()
    if (Test-Path "$credPath\cred.csv"){$credMassiv = @(Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path "$credPath\cred.csv")}
    else {$credMassiv = @()}
    $array = "" | Select user, Encrypted, role
    $array.user = read-host "user for $role"
    $pwd = read-host "password:" -AsSecureString
    $array.Encrypted = ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $pwd
    $array.role = $role
    $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $array.user, $pwd
    $credMassiv += $array
    $credMassiv |Export-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 -Path "$credPath\cred.csv"


    $cred
}
$cred = getCred vcenter $PSScriptRoot
Connect-VIServer -Server $serverName -Credential $cred
```

remember, you don't know the encryption key, it is stored in the profile of the current user

Comment: In above code as device IP that is vcenter IP is not used...what if I have same username and password  for multiple vcenters ???

Comment: @NehaJain $serverName = "192.168.1.1"; $serverName2 ="192.168.1.2"; Connect-VIServer -Server $serverName -Credential $cred; ... Disconnect-VIServer $serverName ... Connect-VIServer -Server $serverName2 -Credential $cred

Comment: Issue still exists....after running  the code....in windows event logs....I can see my password  in a log called convertfrom secure string. In this log, password  is stored

Comment: Password  should  not be stored in any of the windows event logs

Comment: please  help here

Comment: @NehaJain I can't find it, add the path and/or screenshots

Comment: CommandInvocation(ConvertTo-SecureString): "ConvertTo-SecureString " ParamterBinding(ConvertTo-SecureString): name = "AsPlainText "; value = "True" ParameterBinding(ConvertTo-SecureString): name="String"; value="Pasa@123"

Comment: Above limes are captured in event viewer. "Pasa@123" is my vcenter original password before encryption. Path is Applications and Services\Microsoft \Windows\Powershell \operational event log is 4103

Comment: looks like usage of convertTo-SecureString is creating volunarabilty of password  showcase in event logs.. Is there any other way of encrypting password  before we call vcenter server.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/debug-customscriptextension-runcommand-scripts

Comment: not logging off or script block...Just iam trying to find other ways of encryption of password In powershell.  Iam unable  yo get that

Comment: Tried few encryption techniques like convertTosecureString  ,ConvertFrom-SecureString and pscredential. In all these scenarios  iam able to see my plaintext password  in event log. Even though encrypted string or pscrential is passed as password to vcenter method call

Comment: I don't have an event with code 4103, apparently my logging level is lower than yours

Comment: May be it is logging with another event code.. just try export  complete log to csv. Search with vcenter cleartext password  in excel, you will get password in excel

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/debug-customscriptextension-runcommand-scripts#understand-the-output https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/debug-customscriptextension-runcommand-scripts#turn-off-logging-of-powershell-script-execution

Comment: Above link is not useful

Comment: what is the problem with Disabling PowerShell script execution logging?

Comment: I have tried disabling   but still logging  is happening.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75692355/powershell-logging-is-not-diasabling-in-event-viewer-even-though-block-and-off-t

Comment: enable powershell  script  blocking in registry as well as in local computer policy. Then you will be able to see 4103 log. And then issue will be reproduced

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect that [Connect-VIServer](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/powercli/latest/vmware.vimautomation.core/commands/connect-viserver/#Default) accepts a encrypted password?

It does accept a credential which includes a username and a (encrypted) password:

```
$Credentials = Get-Credential
```

See also: [Using PowerShell credentials without being prompted for a password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6239647/1701026)

> ⚠️ in the interest of security, try to avoid using hardcoded authentication in a script (as anybody can reuse that), instead authenticate the user (account) that runs the script.

```
Connect-VIServer -Server $serverName -Credential $Credential
```