# Powershell logging is not diasabling in event viewer even though block and off the logging

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powercli, event-viewer, vcenter

I wanted to stop the logging of powershell in event viewer operational logs when powershell scripts executed.

I have disabled modular logging and powershell script block logging in Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows PowerShell

But above is not logging off the logs in event viewer, powershell\operational path logging.

Can someone  guide ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_eventlogs?source=recommendations&view=powershell-5.1

Comment: As mentioned  in above link I disabled modular logging,  but still logging  is happening  in event viewer